# Which function should I use to output a parabola-sigmoid-like of maximum $n$, $0 \le n \le 1$, with input of $0$ to $1$

Tags: functions

It could be a simple question but I can't find the answer.

I have an input which is a decimal value between $0$ and $1$.
I need to find a function, sort of a parabolic sigmoid, which returns $1$ at its maximum, $n$ between $0$ and $1$, and progressively tend to $0$ when input tends to $0$ or $1$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with a cubic $f(x) = ax^3 +bx^2 + cx$. That function is $0$ at $0$.

Since $f(1) = 0$, 
$$
a + b + c = 0 .
$$

Since $f(n) = 1$, 
$$
an^3 + bn^2 + cn= 1 .
$$

Since $n$ is the maximum the derivative is $0$ there so
$$
3an^2 + 2bn + c = 0 .
$$

Since $n$ is known, you have three linear equations to solve for the three coefficients.

Warning: check that the function is positive on the unit interval - it might not be.

Another idea is to start with the parabola
$$
 x^2 - x
$$
and then find a function $g$ mapping the unit interval to itself that distorts the values on the $x$-axis to move the maximum at $1/2$ to $n$ where you want it. Your answer would be
$$
f(x) = g(x)^2 1 g(x).
$$

PS. "[sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)" is not the shape you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suggested sigmoid only for the fact that I wanted a function of minimum 0 and maximum 1. But yeah, I do need a parabolic func. I will try your idea, see if I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, I found the function I wanted. It is a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) which solves exactly my problem.

$\displaystyle f(x, \mu, s) = \frac{ { 1 } }{s(e ^ \frac{ { x - \mu } } {{2s} } + e ^ \frac{ { -x - \mu } } {{2s} })^2}$

(The function can also be seen [here](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=%5Cdisplaystyle%20f(x%2C%20%5Cmu%2C%20s)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B%20%7B%201%20%7D%20%7D%7Bs(e%20%5E%20%5Cfrac%7B%20%7B%20x%20-%20%5Cmu%20%7D%20%7D%20%7B%7B2s%7D%20%7D%20%2B%20e%20%5E%20%5Cfrac%7B%20%7B%20-x%20-%20%5Cmu%20%7D%20%7D%20%7B%7B2s%7D%20%7D)%5E2%7D))